# How can I group these closer together?

Tags: html, image

I just finished my logo for my site and now the users avatar, username and all of the tabs are too far down, how can I make it so the text is closer to the logo: http://serverlauncherplus.co.uk/Skins4Accounts/index.php

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <style>
        body, html {height:100%;}
        wholePage.wrap {height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
        body {overflow: hidden; }
        .ellipsis {
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        .Logoimg {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .column {
            -webkit-column-count: 3;
            -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
        }
        ::selection {
            background: #474746; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
        }
        ::-moz-selection {
            background: #474746; /* Gecko Browsers */
        }
        .tradeURL {
-moz-box-shadow:inset -4px 13px 17px -15px #e67a73;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset -4px 13px 17px -15px #e67a73;
box-shadow:inset -4px 13px 17px -15px #e67a73;
background-color:#e4685d;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:2px solid #ffffff;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:12px 31px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:-1px 3px 27px #b23e35;
}
.tradeURL:hover {
    background-color:#eb675e;
}
.tradeURL:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
            if([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
    <title>AccountFury | Deposit Skins For Accounts!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wholePage">
    <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">

            <div class="top">

                <h1 align="center"><img class="Logoimg" src="http://serverlauncherplus.co.uk/Skins4Accounts/Logo.png"/></h1>

                <!-- Logo -->
                    <div id="logo">
                        <span class="image avatar48"><img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" alt="" /></span>
                        <h1 style="margin-left: 60px" class="ellipsis" id="title"><?php echo $username; ?></h1>
                        <p>Account ID: <?php echo $accid; ?></p>
                    </div>

                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#Dashboard" id="dashboard-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-home">Dashboard</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Deposit" id="Deposit-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-th">Deposit</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#orderAccounts" id="order-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-shopping-cart">Order Accounts</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Settings" id="order-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-cogs">Settings</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Support" id="support-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-question-circle">Support</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

            </div>
```

Comment: brilliant title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this CSS to the `div` with the id `logo` (`<div id="logo">`)

```
#logo{
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Or by applying it directly to the tag like so:

```
<div id="logo" style="margin-top:0;">
```

That will make everything shift up.

If you wish for it to be even closer to the image you can actually give the margin a negative margin like so:

```
<div id="logo" style="margin-top:-40px;">
```

Make sure you specify the units (in this case `px`)

Comment: Are you sure? I added before after images to the post to show what it does. It this what you want @Matt142

Comment: Ah yes, it was because the change was very subtle is there a way so the logo can be around 5px down from the top and the text higher up even more?

Comment: Yes, there is. If you want to move the image logo down `5px` from the top you can do this: `<img class="Logoimg" src="http://serverlauncherplus.co.uk/Skins4Accounts/Logo.png" style="padding-top: 5px;">`. If you look back at the answer I edited it again to show you how to move the text higher up

Answer (score 0):

You have this css rule (in main.css line 2219)

```
 #main > section {
    padding: 3em 0;
 }
```

that adds a top and bottom padding of `3em` to your `section` with id `Dashboard`. The following rule can solve it

```
#main > section#Dashboard {
   padding: 0;
}
```